# Is there a maximal prime number not being a sum of consecutive primes?

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Let $\mathcal S=\{p\in\mathbb P|\exists m,n\in\mathbb Z_+:p=p_n+\cdots+p_{n+m}\}$. For "small" primes, not much greater than one million, it seems that about half of the primes belong to $\mathcal S$. But the greater primes the more combinations of consecutive primes available.

There are $\pi(p)$ primes less than or equal to $p$ and the number of available prime sequences is 
$1\cdot\pi(p)+2\cdot(\pi(p)-1)+3(\pi(p)-2)+\cdots+(\pi(p)-1)\cdot 2=$
$\displaystyle\frac{\pi(p)^3+3\pi(p)^2+4\pi(p)}{6}$
(If I calculated it right).

I suppose it's possible to use the Prime Number Theorem to estimate the probability of $p\in\mathcal S$, but I'm pretty sure that I would mess it up.

My questions are:

> Does $P(p\in\mathcal S)\to 1$ as $p\to\infty$?
>   Can it be proved that there is a maximal prime number not being a sum of consecutive primes?

See also [How often is a sum of $k$ consecutive primes also prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619388/how-often-is-a-sum-of-k-consecutive-primes-also-prime) which is a similar but not an equivalent question.

---

[image]

This is what I got so far. It doesn't support my intuition, but I will let it run up to $10,000,000$ or more.

Comment: What happens if you bind the length of the sum? What is the result?

Answer (score 4):

[A067377](https://oeis.org/A067377) might help.  I've started a bigger run to plot out behavior.

mm = Select[
   Union[Flatten[
     Table[Total /@ Partition[Prime[Range[200000]], n, 1], {n, 2, 
       1000}]]], PrimeQ];

Here's the behavior.  Roughly 44% of primes are sums of consecutive primes at that point.  Chaotic.

[image]